# 160-bit fingerprint of RSA key

Tags: ssh, hashsum, fingerprint

The command

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

prints the **128-bit** fingerprint of the RSA key.

What is the command to get the **160-bit** fingerprint of a RSA key?

Comment: Why do you expect a 160-bit fingerprint? What tool supports this?

Comment: I'm troubleshooting an obscure piece of software which connects to a SSH server and outputs the host key as a 40-hex digits (160 bits) fingerprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key fingerprint is a hash of the key material. In a public key file, the key material is the second whitespace-separated field on the line, encoded in base64. The display format for the fingerprint depends on the hash that's being used.

The 128-bit fingerprint uses MD5 and is displayed in hexadecimal. For example, the following commands display the same fingerprint, with different punctuation and surrounding material:

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub -l -E md5
</etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | md5sum
```

The SHA256 fingerprint (256 bits) is displayed in Base64. Again, here are two commands to display the fingerprint.

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub -l -E sha256
</etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | openssl sha -sha256 -binary | base64
```

If you need a 160-bit fingerprint, it's using SHA-1, which was never commonly supported (I think SHA-1 wasn't introduced as an alternative to MD5 until a time when SHA-1 itself was deprecated). Current versions of OpenSSH don't support it, but you can use either of the alternative methods above with `sha1` instead of `md5` or `sha256`, depending on whether you need the hex or base64 format.

Comment: Thank you. The command I used was `< /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | openssl sha1`, and it effectively printed the hash in hex format, which was what I needed.